# GitBook generates epub with duplicate headings

Tags: epub, gitbook, calibre

I have ebook in markdown files and use GitBook for generating epub file. Like usual, chapters are defined in SUMMARY.md and chapter files begins with a headings (the same like in summary):

```
Title of the chapter
====================
```

GitBook uses Calibre's tool [ebook-convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html) to generate epub files what will have html files with title section like:

```
  <body class="calibre">

<div class="page">

        <h1 class="book-chapter2" id="calibre_toc_2">Title of the chapter</h1>
        <div class="section">
            <h1 id="příběh-první" class="calibre17">Title of the chapter</h1>
```

First h1 have `display: none` in CSS, so will not be visible in most readers, but some of them ignores it and renders heading twice.

Is there a way hot to configure GitBook or epub-convert to not add second heading and keep table of contents working?

Comment: Why are you using two different tags? If you do that because of the spine link to the actual chapter, you should know that can use more than just an ID or a Class in the attributes... Anyway since you haven't posted any css snippet I assume there are some conflicting display properties, which you can override by using `display: none !important` inside a style attribute. It's not the best solution but it should work.

Comment: @crystian What two different tags you mean?
No own CSS, only that inherited from GitBook.

Comment: There are two <h1> tags with the same text. It's considered a bad practice to use two different tags and hide the first when you can use just one and link the index to that one.

Comment: I know. That is what I asked about - why it generates two redundant headings.

Comment: Actually, if you were able to set the command line options you could use `--search-replace` regex option to fix it.

Comment: It is option of ebook-convert? Do you know how to use GitBook to pass options to ebook-convert?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to replace two headings with one what will have id from the first h1 and content form the second h1?